# Display textview below imageview and not bottom to the parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm working on an Android application and I have an issue with how to display an image in a view. My issue is that I want to display an image and two textViews just below my imageView without aligning their bottom to the parent's. See the wireframe below.

My problem is that when the imageView is taking all the height of the relativeLayout, my textViews are hidden below the parents view.

I have tried a lot of things but nothing is satisfaying...
I have tried to put my imageview in a linearLayout and put a weight on it but if my imageView is smaller I have a blank between the imageView and the textView.

It's complicated because each image I load can have a different size and thus I can't fix a default size to it.
Also, my layout is in a viewPager and when I want to have the Height of the view when I instantiate it on my adapter it returns 0. So I can't compute the size of the elements in the view.

Have you any idea how can I make my layout ?

Maybe in a coordinatorLayout to have circular dependencies (but I don't know how to make it) ?

Here a wireframe of what I want to do with my view: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeQqJ.png)

And here the code of my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/layout_photo_detail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_photo_detail_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relative_photo_detail_bottom_infos">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_detail_full_size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/photo_detail_owner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/photo_detail_full_size"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_photo_detail_bottom_infos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relative_photo_detail_image"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_detail_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code inside Scroll view

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have already thinking about a scroll view but the result is not what I want. The textviews can be hidden and the user will not think immediately to scroll and see if there are informations below the image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, It's not the solution I'm looking for. As I stated in the question, I don't want to align my two textviews bottom to the parent view. All the images have different size, so if an image don't take all the height of the screen, I want my textviews just below it and not fixed at the bottom of the parent view.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this solution but it doesn't work if the image is big and take all the height of the layout. The textviews are hidden under the view...

Comment: If the image is too big .set the  `maxheight` of `ImageView `programmatically.

Comment: I have thinking about it. But when I initiate the item on my adapter (because it's a view pager) and I want to know the height of my textviews, it returns 0... How can I know the height of the elements and set a maxHeight to my imageView ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update your layout structure as below:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_photo_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TextView 2 -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photo_detail_owner_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="This is TextView Two"/>

    <!-- TextView 1 -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photo_detail_owner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/photo_detail_owner_description"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="This is TextView One"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_photo_detail_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/photo_detail_owner"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <!-- Image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_detail_full_size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <!-- Delete Icon -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_detail_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: To whom it may concern. May I know the reason of down-vote?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, It's not the solution I'm looking for. As I stated in the question, I don't want to align my two textviews bottom to the parent view. All the images have different size, so if an image don't take all the height of the screen, I want my textviews just below it and not fixed at the bottom of the parent view.

Comment: Then you can use `ScrollView` as root layout and use `ImageView` height as `wrap_content`

Comment: But I don't want to use scrollview, it's not user friendly for this view. If the image is big and hide the textviews, the user will not think to scroll the view.

Comment: If your image size is bigger than your screen size then how do you show the full image on screen?

Comment: The image is resized automatically by the height of the layout. But the imageView don't care if there are other elements (like my textviews) below it and give all the space to the image.